# How do I isolate only certain text to be scraped using watir for ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, watir

trying to learn watir / ruby better and I am trying to write a code to go to ebay listings based on hockey players and search for cards but I only want to scrape the results of the search not the rest of the page. is there a way to sandwich it so I only scrape the text between "Save This Search" and "Results" eg.below

code:

```
require 'watir'
require 'webdrivers'


puts 'Enter a Name: '
name = gets.chomp

puts 'PSA, BGS, or RAW?'
grade = gets.chomp.downcase
if grade == 'raw'
    grade = ''
end   


browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto('ebay.ca')

browser.wait(5) { browser.text_field.exists? }
browser.text_field.set "#{name} young guns #{grade}"
browser.send_keys :enter

puts browser.text 



sleep(3)
```

**Save this search**
Shipping to: V1B2C7
2005-06 UPPER DECK #201 SIDNEY CROSBY YOUNG GUNS RC GRADED BGS 9.5 "GEM MINT"
Brand New
C $1,084.00
Time left
5d 5h left (Sun., 06:55 p.m.)
13 bids
+C $12.99 shipping
2005-06 Upper Deck #201 Sidney Crosby Young Guns True Gem BGS 9.5 w/ 10
Sub Centering 9.5 Corners 9.5 Edges 9.5 Surface 10
C $2,199.95
Top Rated Seller
Buy It Now
+C $12.00 shipping
12 watchers
2005/06 Sidney Crosby Young Guns #201
New (Other)
C $1,150.00
or Best Offer
+C $20.99 shipping
22 watchers
2005-06 Upper Deck #201 Sidney Crosby YG RC Young Guns Please Read REPRINT
C $9.99
Time left
16h 58m left (Wed., 06:18 a.m.)
1 bid
Top Rated Seller
+C $2.99 shipping
Conner Mcdavid,Crosby,Matthews,Gretzky,Price,Young Guns Reprints
Brand New
C $12.50
Time left
3d 7h left (Fri., 09:01 p.m.)
5 bids
+C $3.00 shipping
2005 Upper Deck Young Guns #201 Sidney Crosby RC Rookie Gem Mint PSA 10
Brand New
C $1,761.76
Time left
2d 6h left (Thu., 07:41 p.m.)
17 bids
Top Rated Seller
+C $49.40 shipping
From United States
Customs services and international tracking provided
2005 Upper Deck Young Guns #201 Sidney Crosby RC Rookie Gem Mint PSA 10
Brand New
C $1,829.52
Time left
2d 6h left (Thu., 07:40 p.m.)
11 bids
Top Rated Seller
+C $50.52 shipping
From United States
Customs services and international tracking provided
**Results** Pagination - Page 1
12
Items Per Page50
Items Per Page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can target the specific elements that you are interested in seeing. In this case, the search results are all of the `li` elements with class "sresult".

Therefore, you could get all the text of the search results by doing:

```
results = browser.lis(class: 'sresult')
results.each { |r| puts r.text }
```

This gives a pretty ugly blob of text without any of the information for what each piece of text is - eg title vs price. It may be better to focus on specific elements within each result to pull/format the exact information you want:

```
results.each do |r|
  puts "Title: #{r.h3.text}"
  puts "Price: #{r.li(class: 'lvprice').text}"
  puts
end
```